# Time Complexity- For Loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a Question about calculating the time complexity with O-Notation . We have given this Code ..

```
int a=0; 
For (int j=0; j<n ; j++){ 
    For(int i=0; i*i<j; i++){ 
     a++; } 
}
```

I think the solution ist O(n^2) That for the first for loop we need n and for the second we need n... but I as I answerd the exam Questions..I got zero points for it

... Also for another code

```
 int g(int y){ 
  If (y<10){ 
   Return 1;} 
  else { 
    int a=0; 
    for ( int i=0;i<n;j++) { 
        a++;}
      return a+g(2(y/3)+1)+g(2(y/3)+2)+g(2(y/3)+3);}
 }
```

I think the solution ist O(n) , That the variables time won't be calculated... the if sentence has a constant time O(1) and would be dominated by the for loop and the for loop would have O(n)

.... Also any advises or resources that explains how a program time would be calculated? And thank you :)

Comment: It isn't wrong to say the first code is O(n^2) since big-Oh  is an upper bound. Its just not very precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first code, you have:

```
T(n) = 1 + sqrt(2) + ... + sqrt(n) = Theta(n\sqrt(n))
```

As `i*i < j` means `i < sqrt(j)`. For the second, you can use [Akra-Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) theorem:

```
T(n) = T(2n/3+1) + T(2n/3+2) + T(2n/3+3) + n
```

and reach to `T(n) = 3 T(2n/3) + n` to use the master thorem (~`O(n^2.7)`)

Comment: So how did we come to Theta(n/sqrt(n)) ,, so wie said n for the first for loop and sqrt(n) for the second  ... therfor the multiplication must be Theta (n^1,5) ?

Comment: @Sayuri yes. the first loop is `n` and the inner loop is `sqrt(n)`, so it is `n\sqrt{n}` or `n^1.5`.